# Consultar apenas Data, em um campo DateTime com LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Estou gerando um relatório em um app que estou desenvolvendo, mas to com um probleminha. Ao mandar uma consulta em um intervalo de data, não consigo obter nada, porque ele é um DATETIME (Não posso alterar para somente date, pois preciso da hora em alguns momentos). Então, estou tentando mandar apenas o Date, porém ele retorna um erro.

> Message = "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

```
var query = from td in this.Table.AsNoTracking()
                    join u in base.context.Users on  td.UserId equals u.Id
                    where (!onlyEnabled) || (u.Enable)
                    select td;
            //AQUI TENTO PASSAR APENAS O DATE
        if (initialOpeningDate.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.OpeningDate.Date) >= initialOpeningDate.Value);
          //AQUI TENTO PASSAR APENAS O DATE
        if (finalOpeningDate.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.OpeningDate.Date) <= finalOpeningDate.Value);

        if (onlyExpired)
            query = query.Where(td => td.ExpireDate < DateTime.Now);

        return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua abordagem está correta, usando `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, mas acredito que você possa não passar a conversão para dentro da sentença Linq, resolvendo as variáveis antes, da seguinte forma:

```
    if (initialOpeningDate.HasValue) 
    {
        var queryInitialOpeningDate = initialOpeningDate.Value.Date;
        query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.OpeningDate.Date) >= queryInitialOpeningDate);
      //AQUI TENTO PASSAR APENAS O DATE
    }
    if (finalOpeningDate.HasValue) 
    {
        var queryFinalOpeningDate = finalOpeningDate.Value.Date;
        query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.OpeningDate.Date) <= queryFinalOpeningDate);
    }
```

Comment: Realmente, faltou isso. Mas continua repetindo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Esqueci de citar, que estou usando o EF.

Comment: @ViniciusMatos Ajustei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: consegui resolver. O problema, era o .Date no final. Ele estava "quebrando" minha query. Mas, mto obrigado.